# Difficulty of specifying a within-group correlation structure in a linear mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

Suppose we have a dataset generated in `R` - the response variable `val` is structured with three factors `sub`, `loc` and `time`:

```
require(MASS); require(nlme)
r1 <- 0.8; r2 <- 0.3; ns <- 20; nt <- 100
S1 <- matrix(c(1,r1,
               r1,1),
             nrow=2, ncol=2)
S2 <- matrix(c(1,r2,
               r2,1),
             nrow=2, ncol=2)
tt <- mvrnorm(ns, mu=c(0, 0), Sigma=S1)
dd <- data.frame(sub =rep(paste0('s', 1:ns), each=2*nt),
                 time=rep(paste0('t', 1:nt), times=2*ns),
                 loc =rep(rep(c('l', 'r'), each=nt), times=ns),
                 val =0)
for(s in 1:ns)
  dd[((2*s-2)*nt+1):(2*s*nt), 'val'] <- c(mvrnorm(nt, mu=tt[s,], Sigma=S2))
```

The dataset has the following structure:

```
> str(dd)
'data.frame':   4000 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ sub : Factor w/ 20 levels "s1","s10","s11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ time: Factor w/ 100 levels "t1","t10","t100",..: 1 13 24 35 46 57 68 79 90 2 ...
 $ loc : Factor w/ 2 levels "l","r": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ val : num  0.5081 1.0235 0.3486 0.2187 -0.0908 ...
```

I'd like to implement the following model with the `R` package `nlme` and retrieve the parameter `r2`:

```
m <- lme(val~0+loc, random=~0+loc|sub, data=dd, correlation = corSymm(form=~0+loc|sub:time))
```

However, this does not seem to work as I wanted:

> Error in lme.formula(val ~ 0 + loc, random = ~0 + loc | sub, data =
> dd,  :    incompatible formulas for groups in 'random' and
> 'correlation'

The reason for the failure seems to be that the within-group variance-covariance matrix is not structured the same as that (or a subset) of the population-level variance-covariance matrix?

Is there a way to implement the model with `nlme`? Or hack the function `lmer` in the `lme4` package somehow? Thanks!

=========
**P.S.: an extended case**========

The factor `loc` in the original data had 2 levels. Suppose now there are 3 levels with the factor `loc`:

```
require(MASS)
r1 <- 0.7; r2 <- 0.3; r3 <- 0.5
r4 <- 0.6; r5 <- 0.4; r6 <- 0.8
ns <- 20; nt <- 100
S1 <- matrix(c(1,r1,r2,
               r1,1,r3,
               r2,r3,1),
             nrow=3, ncol=3)
S2 <- matrix(c(1,r4,r5,
               r4,1,r6,
               r5,r6,1),
             nrow=3, ncol=3)
tt <- mvrnorm(ns, mu=c(0, 0, 0), Sigma=S1)
dd <- data.frame(sub =rep(paste0('s', 1:ns), each=3*nt),
                 time=rep(paste0('t', 1:nt), times=3*ns),
                 loc =rep(rep(c('l', 'm', 'r'), each=nt), times=ns),
                 val =0)
for(s in 1:ns)
  dd[((3*s-3)*nt+1):(3*s*nt), 'val'] <- c(mvrnorm(nt, mu=tt[s,], Sigma=S2))
```

Can we retrieve the 3 correlations `r4`, `r5`, and `r6` in this case?

The following approach sort of works, but it's not ideal:

```
m <- lme4::lmer(val~(0+loc|sub/time), data=dd, 
            control = lme4::lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
```

Is there a better parameterization that is similar to the last solution by @Sextus Empiricus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can model this as a nested structure

```
m <- lme(val~0, random=~0+loc|sub/time, data=dd)
```

You have a random effect for the subjects, for which you compute 20 times a bivariate location sample.

And a random effect for each time nested within the subjects, for which you compute 20 x 100 times a bivariate location sample.

Edit:

you can also use the following formula defining the correlation structure of the locations within the groups time nested inside the subjects. This function `corSymm` requires that the covariate is integer-valued and in order to do this you can use `as.numeric(loc)`  inside the formula

```
m <- lme(val ~ 0, random=~0+loc|sub, data=dd, 
         correlation = corSymm(form=~0+as.numeric(loc)|sub/time))
```

Expressing the random effect of the subjects as a correlation structure solves the problem with the ambiguity between the random effect and the random error that is described below.

---

#### Modeling with lmer

You can also use `lmer`, but then you need to suppress the warning using the control parameter.

```
m <- lme4::lmer(val~(0+loc|sub/time), data=dd, 
            control = lme4::lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
```

The reason for this is that your model consist of 20 samples from a bivariate distribution, one for each of the 20 subjects

$$\vec{x}_i \sim MVN\left(\mu = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho_1\\ \rho_1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

and 2000 samples from a bivariate distribution, one hundred for each of the 100 times per subject.

$$\vec{y}_{ij} \sim MVN\left(\mu = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho_2\\ \rho_2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Then your dependent variable is the sum of those where the subscripts $i$ and $j$ relate to the subject id and time id.

$$\begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}_{ij} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}_i + 
  \begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}_{ij}$$

The linear mixed-effects models use a different model and has an additional residual term.

$$\begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2\end{bmatrix}_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}_i + \begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix}_{ij} + \begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_1 \\ \epsilon_2\end{bmatrix}_{ij}$$

This makes that the correlation structure is dependent from the $\epsilon$ and can not be determined uniquely (you can make the same model with different combinations of correlation matrices $\Sigma$ and $\epsilon$).

The `lme` function somehow ignores it and estimates an $\epsilon$ with a very tiny value for the variance.

---

#### Example Demonstration

below we have a computation where we use `lmer` to model the part $\vec{y}_{ij}$

$$\vec{y}_{ij} \sim MVN\left(\mu = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \rho_2\\ \rho_2 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right) $$

as equivalent to

$$\vec{y}_{ij} = \vec{z}_{ij} + \vec{\epsilon}_{ij}$$

with $\vec{z}_{ij}$ fully correlated (like a random intercept term) and $\epsilon$ completely independent (like a random noise term).

$$\vec{z}_{ij} \sim MVN\left(\mu = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \rho_2 & \rho_2\\ \rho_2 & \rho_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

$$\vec{\epsilon}_{ij} \sim MVN\left(\mu = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1-\rho_2 & 0\\ 0 & 1-\rho_2\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

```
m <- lme4::lmer(val~0+(0+loc|sub)+(1|sub:time), data=dd)
summary(m)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: val ~ 0 + (0 + loc | sub) + (1 | sub:time)
   Data: dd

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 11632.1  11663.6  -5811.0  11622.1     3995 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9409 -0.5866 -0.0003  0.6080  3.3442 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 sub:time (Intercept) 0.3347   0.5785       
 sub      locl        0.9014   0.9494       
          locr        0.6643   0.8151   0.84
 Residual             0.7488   0.8654       
Number of obs: 4000, groups:  sub:time, 2000; sub, 20
```

In this case the control parameter is not necessary. The modeled covariance of $y_{ij}$ is computed from the lines

> ```
> sub:time (Intercept) 0.3347   0.5785
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Residual             0.7488   0.8654
> ```

$$\hat\Sigma_y = \begin{bmatrix} 0.3347+0.7488 & 0.3347 \\ 0.3347 & 0.3347+0.7488  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1.0835 & 0.3347 \\ 0.3347 & 1.0835  \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Very interesting! Sorry, I should have added the model formulation in addition to the `R` code. Actually I first tried `lmer(val~1+(0+loc|sub/time), data=dd)` with `lme4` and it whined with the error message `the random-effects parameters and the residual variance are unidentifiable`. That's why I didn't even bother this with `lme(val~1, random=~0+loc|sub/time, data=dd)`. I'm baffled now: why does the same model formulation work with `nlme`, but not `lme4`?

Comment: You're just amazing! I really appreciate your great help!

Comment: @bluepole I have changed the final part. Using the contrast variable is not neccesary.

Comment: Yep, the new parameterization with the lme4 specification makes perfect sense. What an elegant solution!

Comment: I added a case with 3 levels for the factor `loc` in the original post. Any good solution? Thanks!

Comment: @bluepole I have made an edit that works with the 3 levels. It is in the end not so difficult. (I did not know yet much about these functions like pdSymm and corSymm).

Comment: The only thing left is that the variances are not modelled as the same. I could not see a function that allows you to get a covariance matrix with all the values on the diagonal fixed. You can do some things with pdClasses. For instance the use of `random=~0+loc|sub` is equivalent to `random = list(sub = pdSymm(form = ~ 0 + loc))` but with the standard pdClasses it seems there is no solution that has all values on the diagonal fixed but on the off-diagonal unstructured.

Comment: You could manually minimize the maximum likelihood with `optim` if you want to make it more flexible. Or you could make your own pdClass although I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @bluepole I did not know that either. The pdClass and corClass stuff sounded like magic to me before but now I get them and I could hunt down the problem more easily (which was eventually just starting to read the manual which states that the variable needs to be an integer).

Comment: You're a magician! Your suggestion `corSymm(form=~0+as.numeric(loc)|sub/time` is similar to what I initially thought: I didn't realize in this case I have to convert the factor `loc` to numeric through `as.numeric(loc)` in `corSymm`. It's not an issue as to whether to keep the variances fixed.

Comment: It would seem to be much easier not to resort to random effects to handle serial within-subject correlation patterns but to model serial correlation directly.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, Dr. Harrell! The modeling specifications provided by Sextus Empiricus do seem to work very well in retrieving the correlations. Do you mind showing the method you're referring to with the simulated data in the original post?