# Variance explained by similarity matrix

Tags: r, mixed-model, covariance-matrix

Given a vector $Y$ for $N$ subjects and a matrix $X$ of $d$ variables for each of our $N$ subjects, we can compute matrix $M$, a $N$x$N$ random effects matrix for how similar each of our $N$ subjects are to each other, across our $d$ variables in $X$. For instance, via a correlation. I can then run a mixed effects model regression where $Y$ is my DV and where $M$ describes the similarity between the $N$ participants. **My question is:** How much variance in $Y$ is explained by the random effects matrix $M$? Specifically, I am looking for a worked example in R that does not use pedigrees, yielding both an estimate of the variance explained, as well as some estimate of the error.

There have been some prior related questions ([one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60330/include-a-distance-matrix-as-a-random-effect-in-a-mixed-effects-model), [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18563/estimating-random-effects-and-applying-user-defined-correlation-covariance-struc/18568#18568), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245132/single-level-variables-in-mixed-model-lme4-error-in-r)). These examples are either not fully worked, use pedigrees, or don't give an error for the estimate (perhaps this last bit may be trivial, but it would be helpful if someone could walk me through it).

For context, I'm trying to build off the approach in [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1604378113#sec-1), but I'm having difficulty interpreting their [matlab code](https://people.csail.mit.edu/msabuncu/morphometricity/Morphometricity.m). Another paper which applies the approach I'm describing is [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3014363/) ("heritability" is the variance explained by the genetic similarity between individuals). I am essentially trying to apply this approach in a general manner.

So far, based on prior questions, I've worked out something using `coxme::lmekin()`, but I'm not sure it's correct, particularly whether the similarity matrix I'm giving the function is being handled the way I expect, as the function was written for a pedigree. I'm probably also not calculating the variance explained by $M$ correctly at the end, but I'm having some difficulty interpreting the `coxme::lmekin()` documentation.

```
> library(clusterGeneration)
> library(MASS)
> library(Matrix)
> library(coxme)
> 
> d=201
> N = 100
> set.seed(1234)
> 
> # simulate covariance matrix
> cov_mat<-clusterGeneration::genPositiveDefMat(dim =d,covMethod = "onion")
> 
> # simulate data
> dat<-MASS::mvrnorm(N,mu = rep(0,d),Sigma = cov_mat$Sigma)
> Y = scale(dat[,1],center = T,scale = T)
> X = dat[,-1]
> 
> # subj similarity, based on data, excluding Y
> M = cor(t(X))
> # check if PD
> if(min(eigen(M)$values)<0){M=Matrix::nearPD(x = M)$mat}
> 
> # rescale correlation to a similarity matrix
> range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
> M.2  =range01(M)
> 
> # each subj gets their own random intercept
> rand = c(1:length(Y))
> 
> # without similarity matrix
> a1=lmekin(Y ~ 1 + (1|rand))
> a1
Linear mixed-effects kinship model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: NULL 
  Log-likelihood = -141.3913 
  n= 100 


Model:  Y ~ 1 + (1 | rand) 
Fixed coefficients
                   Value  Std Error z p
(Intercept) 8.926083e-17 0.09949874 0 1

Random effects
 Group Variable  Std Dev    Variance  
 rand  Intercept 0.09900495 0.00980198
Residual error= 0.9900495 
> # variance explained by random effects is nearly 0
> sum(a1$vcoef$rand)/(var(a1$residuals) + sum(a1$var)+sum(a1$vcoef$rand))
[1] 0.009802
> 
> # with similarity matrix
> a2 =lmekin(Y ~ 1 + (1|rand),varlist = list(M.2))
> a2
Linear mixed-effects kinship model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: NULL 
  Log-likelihood = -130.4529 
  n= 100 


Model:  Y ~ 1 + (1 | rand) 
Fixed coefficients
                Value Std Error    z    p
(Intercept) 0.1686349 0.4971669 0.34 0.73

Random effects
 Group Variable Std Dev   Variance 
 rand  Vmat.1   0.9976159 0.9952375
Residual error= 0.5060629 
> # variance explained by random effects is much larger
> sum(a2$vcoef$rand)/(var(a2$residuals) + sum(a2$var)+sum(a2$vcoef$rand))
[1] 0.7369908
```

Comment: *"Given a vector $$ for $$ subjects  ... How much variance in $$ is explained by $$? "* From this description the relationship between $Y$ and $M$ is not clear.

Comment: Thanks @SextusEmpiricus. I've edited the question to specify that $M$ is a random effects matrix. In a standard mixed effects model the random effects are usually blocking variables - equivalent to a sparse similarity matrix. Here, the random effects similarity matrix is dense.

Comment: My problem with your explanation is that after *"Given a vector $Y$ for $N$ subjects"* there is no further explanation what this vector $Y$ is or does. The next time that $Y$ becomes mentioned is only in the end when you ask about *"how much variance in Y is explained by M?"*

Comment: $Y$ has some correlation with all of the variables in $X$, but I don't want to use those correlations directly. Note that $d$ > $N$.

Comment: What does $X$ have to do with $Y$? You don't explain this. Why would there be some correlation? This is not clear from your explanation. You state that there is a variable $Y$ and a matrix $X$, but not how they are related. How do you compute matrix $M$ and how is $Y$ involved? What are these things and how do they connect?

Comment: *"...matrix for how similar each of our $N$ subjects are to each other, across our $d$ variables in $X$..."* What do the $N$ subjects have to do with the matrix $X$?

Comment: I see, sorry. $X$ consists of $d$ variables from each of our $N$ subjects.

Comment: David B, now that part is clear. So we have a $1 \times N$ vector $Y$ and a $d \times N$ vector $X$ that relate to $d+1$ variables/measurements among $N$ subjects...

Comment: ... what remains unclear to me is what you mean by *"How much variance in $Y$ is explained by the random effects matrix $M$?"* What do you mean by 'variance in *Y*', by 'explained by', and by 'random effects matrix'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142734/discussion-between-david-b-and-sextus-empiricus).

Comment: This model that you describe `Y ~ 1 + (1|ID)` has only two variance components. One for the error within the subject and one for between subjects. There is no description how you want to involve $X$ into the model. Is $X$ supposed to have the same decomposition of variances?

Comment: If we run `lme4::lmer(Y ~ 1 + (1|rand))` then you get the error *"number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: rand)
Execution halted"*. And this makes indeed sense. How is a mixed effects model supposed to know how to split up the variance into the random intercept and the random noise term? With the `lmekin` function this is ignored and it does something more than a linear mixed effects model?

Comment: The lme function ignores it and you can run `nlme::lme(Y ~ 1 , random = ~ 1 | rand)` I thought that lmer can also be made to work with `lme4::lmer(Y ~ 1 + (1|rand), control = lme4::lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))`. It works [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/562698/) but with this example it doesn't (maybe it is the R that I am currently using). Anyway, the models do not make much sense without something that helps to split up the two variances.

Comment: Look at my example code at the bottom of my post. See also this answer to a prior question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8247596/21080524 As I said in my post, I am interested in doing something similar to this post, but *without* a pedigree.

Comment: I have read the `lmekin` package now. I believe now that I get what you are doing. Your initial introduction steered me completely in the wrong direction.